# How do I check if a Sympy function is trigonometric?

Tags: function, sympy, trigonometry

I have defined the following two functions, `fun1` and `fun2`:

```
import sympy as sp

y, t = sp.symbols('y'), sp.symbols('t')

fun1 = -t*y + sp.sin(y)

fun2 = t*y
```

I want to be able to check whether each function is trigonometric. So in theory, with a working function 'check', I would get:

```
check(fun1) == True

check(fun2) == False
```

I've tried `sp.functions.elementary.trigonometric in [fun1]` which returns `False`. I've also tried the same with `sp.sin` replacing `fun1` which also gives a 'False' result. I would like to know if it is possible to do a trigonometric check like this.

Comment: I am stuck on a phone so here's a rough draft -- anyone is welcome to expand this into an answer! Sympy has documentation on how to walk the expression tree in https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/manipulation.htm. You should probably look for all function calls in the "fun" and check whether any is trigonometric.

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting 'page not found' though; do you have an updated link? @MingyeWang

Comment: it's the "Advanced Expression Manipulation" page at https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/manipulation.html. My autocorrect must be acting up. Anyways, smichr's answer seems more clever.

Answer (score 1):

The `has` method will tell you if an expression has a certain object or class, and the TrigonometricFunction object can be tested like this:

```py
>>> from sympy.functions.elementary.trigonometric import TrigonometricFunction
>>> fun1.has(TrigonometricFunction)
True
>>> fun2.has(TrigonometricFunction)
False
```

`sympy.functions.elementary.trigonometric` is a module whereas `TrigonometricFunction` is a class in the module.